# EJB 3.x beans are not deployed at server startup in jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I am migrating my application from EJB 2.x to EJB 3.x. I used annotations and removed bean from ejb-jar.xml and jboss.xml. But I could not found my bean from console.

Is ejb-jar.xml necessary for ejb 3?

### ejb 2.x

### ejb-jar.xml

```
 <session>
    <display-name>Accounting Service</display-name>
    <ejb-name>AccountingEJB</ejb-name>
    <home>com.mysedan.service.accounting.ejb.AccountingHome</home>
    <business-remote>com.mysedan.service.accounting.ejb.Accounting</business-remote>
    <ejb-class>com.mysedan.service.accounting.ejb.AccountingEJB</ejb-class>
    <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
    <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>The mysedan DS</description>
        <res-ref-name>myDS</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
        <lookup-name>java:/myDS</lookup-name>
    </resource-ref>
</session>
```

### jboss.xml

```
<session>
    <ejb-name>AccountingEJB</ejb-name>
    <jndi-name>com.mysedan.service.accounting.ejb.Accounting</jndi-name>
    <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>mysDS</res-ref-name>
        <resource-name>myDS</resource-name>
    </resource-ref>
</session>
```

### ejb 3.x

```
@Singleton
@Startup
@Remote
public interface Accounting  {
-------
-----
}


@Startup
@Stateless
public class AccountingEJB implements Accounting {
    private SessionContext ctx;
------------
--------
}
```

Do I required any additional configuration?

Comment: You should not have to do anything else (just deploy your EJB jar and their JNDI addresses shall appear in the console). If they don't, make sure that you are correctly importing from `javax.ejb` (I've once imported from `org.jboss.seam` by mistake). Also, try to follow [this tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI).

Comment: I imported javax.ejb only.. I followed the same as there in tutorial..But JNDI address does not appear..                  @Stateless
@Remote(Accounting.class)
public class AccountingEJB implements Accounting {}                                                   public interface Accounting  {}

Comment: Sorry user, the problem is somewhere else. Try to create a new Project and follow a tutorial from the scratch ([this one](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/ejb3/how-to-create-a-simple-ejb3-project-in-eclipse-jboss-7-1/) for instance). You are probably doing something wrong when packaging or deploying.

Comment: I already tried that project and run it successfully..but my project is web project not ejb project right.. One thing I noticed that if I use ejb-jar.xml for ejb3 then console displays JNDI address..

Comment: The solution is I replaced ejb-jar_2_0.dtd with ejb-jar_3_0.dtd in ejb-jar.xml...Thanks Anthony for your comments...